# How can compose fuzzy rules in 1-D and 2-D?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

fuzzy implication function based on the interpretation "A entails B" can be expressed as :
$$R_{s}=A \longrightarrow B=\int_{X\times Y} sgn[\mu_{B}(y)-\mu_{A}(x)]/(x,y),$$
or, alternatively,
$$f_{s}(a,b)=sgn(b-a)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } b\geq a \\ 
 0 & \mbox{if } otherwise, \end{cases}  $$ 
where $a=\mu_{A}(x)$ and $b=\mu_{B}(y)$ and $\mu_{A}(x)=\mu_{B}(x)=bell(x,4,3,10)$ and $z=f_{s}(a,b)$ and $(\mu_{Rs}(x,y)= sgn[\mu_{B}(y)-\mu_{A}(x)])$.
I want using above identities to show the fuzzy rule "if x is A or y is B then z is C" which is equivalent to the union of two fuzzy rules "if x is A then z is C" and "if y is B then z is C" under max-min composition.
I would be grateful if anyone help to solve this problem? How can I obtain $\mu_{C}(z)$ and how can I obtain $\mu_{R}(x,z)$, $\mu_{R}(y,z)$? 
I would be grateful if anyone help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

R1: if x is A then z is C ==>  μR1(x,z)=sgn[μA(x)−μC(z)]

R2: if y is B then z is C (we know that μA(x)=μB(y))==>  μR2(x,z)=sgn[μB(y)−μC(z)]

(if x is A then z is C) U (if y is B then z is C) ==>

μR1(x,z) V μR2(x,z) = max(sgn[μA(x)−μC(z)] , sgn[μB(y)−μC(z)]) = 
                      sgn[max(μA(x)−μC(z),μB(y)−μC(z))] =
                      sgn[max(μA(x),μB(y))−μC(z)]  **(1)**

if x is A or y is B then z is C ==> max(μA(x),μB(y)) --> C ==

sgn[max(μA(x),μB(y))−μC(z)] **(2)**

now we see that (1)=(2)

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$.